# Filter search ignore object if it's missing information

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have an ng-repeat that looks like this:

```
<div layout="row" flex layout-wrap layout-margin layout-padding>
     <tile ng-repeat="camp in ctrl.camps | filter:{ctrl.search} track by $index"></tile>
</div>
```

`ctrl.camps` is an object array that looks something like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Hey!",
  "kind": "Something",
  "variation": {
      "type": "Smarty",
      "color": "Blue",
   }
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "More Heys!",
  "kind": "Another thing",
  "variation": {
      "type": "Smarty",
      "color": "Green",
   }
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Hey!",
  "kind": "my kind",
  "variation": {
      "type": "Smarty"
   }//  This one doesn't have a color!
}
```

Notice how `id: 3` doesn't have a variation color.

Now I'm filtering these with an `md-select` that looks like this:

```
<md-input-container>
    <label>Variation color</label>
    <md-select ng-model="ctrl.search.variation.color">
         <md-option ng-click="!null">Empty option</md-option> //I want to be able to clear this selection with the ng-click.. Not sure how.
         <md-option ng-repeat="color in ctrl.colors" value="{{color}}">{{color}}</md-option>
     </md-select>
 </md-input-container>
```

So this works great. It filters my list and everything. However, the issue I am having is that the `md-select` must have a empty option in order to clear the filter.. and when I do select the empty option currently, it does clear, BUT the variation without a color doesn't reappear.

Does anybody know how I can possibly fix this? I want to be able to clear with the `ng-click` but I need all the objects to show up again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the problem like yours.

You should empty your 'search' object.

Because, after your md-select is emptied it looks like this :

```
{
  "variation": {color:""}
}
```

So Filter-model is checking does element has any value for variation.color

You can add function to `ng-change` which will check if search.variation.color is empty, then remove it: `delete search.variaton.color` or `$watch` on `$scope.search`

Comment: That is helpful, but if I have multiple `md-select`s that all filter something else then wouldn't `search = {}` clear ALL of my filters? I just want it to clear that specific filter.. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes I understand. Just delete color property: `delete search.variation.color`

Comment: I tried doing `search.variation.color = {};` but I get an error `Cannot set property 'color' of undefined`.. any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Error you got is saying that, 'variation' is undefined.
Maybe you need to check if it exists, like `if(search.variation){.....}`

Anyway you need not  to empty color property like `search.variation.color = {}` 
but delete it! Pay attention, `delete` is javascript operator for objects. Write this way:
`delete search.variation.color`